# Rails, heroku postgres crane returns empty result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-postgres

We are using heroku as an deployment service.Our postgres add-on plan is crane with 400 mb memory limit and we have 460MB data in our database.Until 2 days ago, sometimes postgres server started to response empty result set.

Here is an example about this situation
we have an attribute for our Entry model and after save callback which assigns entry no to entry object but this entry no is different from object_id.
Here is our callback method.

```
def assign_entry_no
  return true unless self.new_record? && !self.project.nil?
  last_entry = Entry.where(:project_id => self.project_id).last
  self.entry_no = last_entry.nil? ? 1 : (last_entry.entry_no + 1)
end
```

Here is the output.

```
object_id -> id
---------|----
677467 -> 3
677466 -> 2
677465 -> 1 // empty result set
677462 -> 3
677461 -> 2
677460 -> 1 // empty result set
677459 -> 31
677458 -> 30
677457 -> 29
```

As you can see, sometimes postgres server returns empty result set. 
We thought that if we upgrade add-on plan to 800 mb, we will solve the issue.
Is there anyone who encounter this problem before, is it about postgres server or another thing?

Our system => rails 3.0.2, mri ruby 1.9.3

Comment: When you say `last_entry`, do you mean to get the latest entry? If so, the following line is NOT guarenteed to give you the latest line `last_entry = Entry.where(:project_id => self.project_id).last`. You must order the results like this `last_entry = Entry.where(:project_id => self.project_id).order('created_at desc').last`

Comment: Did you read our callback code clearly? If there is NO RECORD this code assigns 1 for entry no.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you are handling the case where there are NO records. My point was that when there are some records, the query does not necessarily return the LATEST record as you have not ordered it by time.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Postgres plans give you a dedicated amount of **cache** space. You can go over 400mb on the Crane plan, but some of your queries may respond slower because the database has to access data from the disk.

My assumption is that your `assign_entry_no` method is not doing what you think it is.

I'll dissect the method line-by-line to show you a few improvements and the issues that you may be running into.

```
  return true unless self.new_record? && !self.project.nil?
```

This line should do what you think it does. However, you can clean it up a bit by reversing the conditions to something like `if self.persisted? && self.project_id.present?`. This would keep you from doing `unless` and then undoing the `unless` on your `!self.project.nil?` clause. Additionally, using `project_id` instead of `project` saves you a database query.

```
  last_entry = Entry.where(:project_id => self.project_id).last
```

This is the problem line. First, you have no ordering on the select, so you may end up with inconsistent results. I would suggest doing something like `Entry.where(project_id: project_id).order(id: :desc).first`. This way you are somewhat guaranteed to get the last id (concurrency issues aside).

The other problem is that you are scoping on `:project_id`. I suspect that when you create a new project (say, `id = 44`), your query is `SELECT id FROM entries WHERE project_id = 44 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`. Since project #44 is new, there are no entries, so you get an empty set. This causes the next line to assign `entry_no` to `1`. You are likely to get unique `[project_id, entry_no]` sets, but not `[entry_no]` attributes. I say likely, because in a concurrent environment you could end up having two entries being created at the same time that both get the same `last_entry` record before saving the new entry.

```
  self.entry_no = last_entry.nil? ? 1 : (last_entry.entry_no + 1)
```

This line seems fine enough, if it is what you intend to do. Some people prefer the syntax `self.entry_no = if last_entry.nil? then 1 else last_entry.entry_no + 1 end`, but the logic is the same.

### Conclusions

If you really want a unique `entry_no` for every entry record, why not just use the `id` column? It's auto-incremented and guaranteed by the database to be unique. If you want uniqueness for [project_id, entry_no] pairs, then your code generally does this already. Run the SQL query `SELECT id, project_id, entry_no FROM entries;` and you should see this. If this is what you want, I would suggest adding a unique index to your `entries` table on `[:project_id, :entry_no]`, so that you are guaranteed not to get duplicates.

Comment: Your answer is really good and thank you for your attention.However, I do not find what exactly causes this problem.

Comment: What result do you get when you run `SELECT project_id, entry_no, COUNT(*) FROM entries GROUP BY project_id, entry_no;`? You should see that each `project_id, entry_no` pair is unique, but **not** every `entry_no` is unique.